# Django-Rest-Framework field naming remap

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have python classes written in pythonic naming conventions (e.g. `multiple_words_with_underscores`). When exposed through Django-Rest-Framework, I want to redo the naming convention to `camelCase` to be more javascript-esque. Is there a built in way to do this with the Django-Rest-Framework serializers or do I need to explicitly name the columns?

I know how I can achieve this with list comprehension and the model._meta.fields attribute, I just want to know if there is a specific built-in way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use djangos field.verbose_name attribute like this:

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='New name')
```

This is automatically used in the POST/PUT forms but not in the object representation. You can  have your frontend use this parameter where necessary to show the labels you wish